# Duration between two questions which I can ask

Tags: support, questions, post-ban

How frequently I  an ask a question?  Stack exchange says we are no longer accepting questions from this account why?

Answer (score 4):

That's the message you see when you are subject to an automated question ban. These bans are [explained in detail on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th), so please read that post. You should also read the documentation that is linked from the message you see.